# has_many :through or has_and_belongs_to_many or something else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, associations

I have a Project and User model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :proposer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
end
```

I want there to be a User who was the Project proposer and owns the project. and then there to be other users who also own the project. The User/proposer adds them as owners for example but they are not the proposer.

How would I model this? I currently only have the proposer relationship established. This is a bit confusing as I am still learning more advanced associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => project_users
    has_many :project_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects, :through => project_users
    has_many :project_users
end
```

Now in your `ProjectUser` table with `user_id` and `project_id` add an extra column `role`. This role field will define the `user` role, is he a **proposer** or normally just **own** the projects.

Then if you want to find the project proposer, then `project.project_users.where(:role => 'proposer')`

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up doing this(not sure if it is good solution long term):

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :proposer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :propojectships
  has_many :users, through: :projectships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projectships
  has_many :projects, through: :projectships
  has_many :projects
end
```

I have a join table Projectships which holds one relation and then I have the direct foreign key with no join table which holds the proposer relationship. It seems to work thus far. Although I think the solution above/below by @Emu is better I may come back and change to that if I run into any problems.